# In MVC, how does one use both Bind (to prevent overposting) and [Required] Fields at the same time? (more inside)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

So, I want to use Bind to prevent overposting attacks and also use [Required] fields.  These two seem impossible to use together.  Here is why:

Let's say you have the class below.  You want the Title to be required in the Create View, so that every movie has a title, but after the movie is created you don't want the user to be able to edit the title, so you don't include Title in the Bind statement for the Edit Action.

```
public class Movie 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Director{ get; set; }
}
```

And this Post method for Edit:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="ID,Director")] Movie movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(movie).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(movie);
}
```

ModelState.IsValid will always be false.  ModelState.IsValid will never be true here because the class demands a value for the Title field, but when editing you never want the user to be able to change this field.

I can't see a way to make this work.  Am I just thinking about this in a wrong manner, or what?

Comment: How about passing the same title.....

Comment: Passing the title from the View (even in hidden form) can be exploited in an overpost attack.

Answer (score 2):

Define separate (view-)models for Create and Edit actions, e.g. `MovieCreateViewModel` (having `[Required]Title` attribute) and `MovieEditViewModel` (without `[Required]`).